# Removing form validation on an input field

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a simple upload script that has some validation on the form. The idea behind the upload form is to upload 2 images, one a thumbnail and one a larger image. Both need to be the correct dimensions and require an image to be selected in order for the form to validate and successfully upload the images.

However, I have been tasked to remove the first upload part, the thumbnail. We now only need the larger image. Though I'm unsure how to remove the validation part of the process. I have tried to remove the input field from the HTML, but obviously the upload script sees this as not upload the first image and throws an error.

Anyway the files:

**Upload.php**

```
 <?php

    // Edit upload location here
    $thumb_destination_path = "../storyslide_thumbs/";
    $large_destination_path = "../storyslide_large/";

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
      $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    }

    $caption = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['caption']);
    $caption2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['caption2']);

    if ($type == "article" || $type == "editarticle") {
      $sql="select a.title, a.category, c.title as cattitle, s.section as stitle, c.type from article a, category c, section s WHERE c.catID=a.category AND c.sectionid=s.sectionid AND a.articleID='$ID'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      $stitle = html_entity_decode($stitle);
      $stitle = punct_remove($stitle);
      $linktitle = html_entity_decode($title);
      $linktitle = punct_remove($linktitle);
      $cattitle = html_entity_decode($cattitle);
      $cattitle = punct_remove($cattitle);

      if ($category=='43') {
        $link = "/fans/obituaries/$ID-$linktitle..html";
      } else {
        if ($type=="Blog") {
          $ID = "b$ID";
          $cattitle = $cattitle . "-" . $category;
        } else {
          $cattitle = $category . "-" . $cattitle;
        }
        $link = "/$stitle/$cattitle/$ID-$linktitle.html";
      }
    } elseif ($type == "player") {
      $sql = "SELECT name FROM player WHERE playerID='$ID'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      $name = html_entity_decode($name);
      $name = punct_remove($name);

      $link = "/players/squad/$ID-$name.html";
    } elseif ($type == "match") {
      $sql="select r.versus, r.venue, s.year FROM regmatch r, season s WHERE r.matchID='$ID' AND r.season=s.seasonID";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      if ($venue=='Home') {
        $teams = "Stanlow V $versus";
        $teams2 = "Stanlow_vs_" . str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus));
      }
      else {
        $teams = "$versus V Stanlow";
        $teams2 = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus)) . "_vs_Stanlow";
      }

      $year = str_replace("/", "-", $year);

      $sql="select count(*) as num3 FROM loungeimages WHERE matchID='$ID'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);



      if ($_POST['p']=="ao") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/awayteam.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="bb") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/bookiekiller.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="tn") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/teamnews.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="s") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/scores.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="l") {
        if ($num3>0) {
          $sql="select MIN(imgID) as minumumimage FROM loungeimages WHERE matchID='$ID' GROUP BY matchID";
          $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          extract($row);

          $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/lounge/$minumumimage.html";
        }
        else { 
          $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/lounge.html";
        }
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="fv") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/fansviews.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="fr") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/fansmatchreport.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="ob") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/offtheball.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="mq") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/matchquotes.html";
      } elseif ($_POST['p']=="mr") {
        $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/matchreport.html";
      }
    }

    elseif ($type == "match2") {
      $sql="select r.versus, r.venue FROM regmatch2 r WHERE r.matchID='$ID'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      if ($venue=='Home') {
        $teams = "Stanlow V $versus";
        $teams2 = "Stanlow_vs_" . str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus));
      }
      else {
        $teams = "$versus V Stanlow";
        $teams2 = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus)) . "_vs_Stanlow";
      }

      if ($_POST['p']=="ao") {
        $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/aboutoppo.html";
      } 
      elseif ($_POST['p']=="bb") {
        $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/de_ja_lards_best_bet.html";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['p']=="tn") {
        $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/teamnews.html";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['p']=="mr") {
        $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/matchreport.html";
      }
      elseif ($_POST['p']=="rank") {
        $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/andys_old_rankin.html";
      }
    }


    elseif ($type == "event") {
      $link = "/fans/diary.html";
    } elseif ($type == "picsubcat") {
      $sql = "SELECT s.title as stitle, c.catID, c.title as ctitle, MIN(p.imgID) as imgID, se.section FROM picturesubcategory s, category c, picturetable p, section se WHERE c.sectionid=se.sectionid AND s.piccatID='$ID' AND s.catID=c.catID AND p.piccatID=s.piccatID";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("<script language='javascript'>alert('" . $sql . "');</script>");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      $ctitle = html_entity_decode($ctitle);
      $ctitle = punct_remove($ctitle);
      $stitle = html_entity_decode($stitle);
      $stitle = punct_remove($stitle);
      $section = strtolower($section);

      $link = "/$section/$catID-$ctitle/$stitle/$imgID.html";
    } elseif ($type == "paypal") {
      $sql = "SELECT name FROM paypalitems WHERE itemID='$ID'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);
      $name = str_replace(" ", "_", $name);
      $name = urlencode($name);
      $link = "/products/" . $ID . "-" . $name . ".html";
    } elseif ($type == "lookalike") {
      $link = "/funnies/lookalikes/1.html";
    } elseif ($type == "wallpaper") {
      $link = "/gear/wallpapers/1.html";
    }

    $result = 0;

    $time = time();

    while(file_exists($time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name']))  
    {  
      $time++;  
    }

    while (file_exists($time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name']))
    {
      $time++;
    }

    $thumb_target_path = $thumb_destination_path . $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $large_target_path = $large_destination_path . $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name'];

    $filename = $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $filename2 = $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name'];

    if ((!isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] == "") || (!isset($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name']) || $_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'] == "")) {
      $result = 3;
    } else {
      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'])) {
        if (getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'])) {
          if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $thumb_target_path)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'], $large_target_path))) {
            $result = 1;

            $image_dim = getimagesize($thumb_target_path);
            $image_dim2 = getimagesize($large_target_path);

            if (($image_dim[0] != 75 || $image_dim[1] != 100) || ($image_dim2[0] != 230 || $image_dim2[1] != 199)) {
              $result = 4;
              unlink($thumb_target_path);
              unlink($large_target_path);
            } else {

              if (isset($_POST['f'])) {
                $publishingdate = $_POST['date'];
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO storyslide_future (thumb, large, thumbcaption, largecaption, link, publishingdate) VALUES ('$filename', '$filename2', '$caption', '$caption2', '$link', '$publishingdate')";
                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad insert statement");</script>');

              } else {

                $sql = "DELETE FROM storyslide WHERE thumbID='16'";
                $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad delete statement");

                $sql1 = "UPDATE storyslide SET thumbID=thumbID+1";
                $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad update statement");</script>');

                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO storyslide (thumbID, thumb, large, thumbcaption, largecaption, link) VALUES ('1', '$filename', '$filename2', '$caption', '$caption2', '$link')";
                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad insert statement");</script>');
              }

            }
          }
        } else {

          $result = 2;

        }
      } else {
        $result = 5;
      } 
    }

    sleep(1);
    ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>




    <?php } ?>
```

And now the form:

```
    <script src='upload_handler.js' language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

      <div id='wrapper'> <!-- start wrapper -->

        <?php include("top.php"); ?>

        <div id='pagetitle'> <!-- start pagetitle -->
          <div id='pageimage'><img src='adminimages/note.jpg'/></div>
          <div id='title'>Add to Thumbnails</div>
        </div> <!-- end pagetitle -->



        <div id='admincontrols'> <!-- start admincontrols -->
          <center>
            <div id='container' style='margin:0 0 0 240px;'>
              <div id="content">
                <form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onSubmit='startUpload();'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='type' value='<?php echo $type; ?>' />
                  <?php
                  if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
                    ?>
                    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='<?php echo $ID; ?>' />
                    <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                  <?php
                  if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
                    ?>
                    <input type='hidden' name='p' value='<?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>' />
                    <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                  <?php
                  if (isset($_GET['f'])) {
                    ?>
                    <input type='hidden' name='f' value='<?php echo $_GET['f']; ?>' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>' />
                    <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                  <p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/><img src="images/loader.gif" width="200" height="20" /><br/></p>
                  <div id='f1_upload_form'>
                    <div id='thumbnail_title' style='font-family:georgia;'>Thumbnail (This Image must be 75px in width and 100px in height):</div>
                    <div class='input_container'>
                      <div class='label_image'>File:</div>
                      <div class='input_image'><input name='myfile' type='file' size='70' class='inputbox'/></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='input_container'>
                      <div class='label_image'>Caption:</div>
                      <div class='input_image'><input name='caption' type='text' maxlength='30' class='inputbox'/></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id='largerimage_title' style='font-family:georgia;'>Main Image (Only one image required. Minimum dimensions: 230px in width and 199px):</div>
                    <div class='input_container'>
                      <div class='label_image'>File:</div>
                      <div class='input_image'><input name='myfile2' type='file' size='70' class='inputbox'/></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='input_container'>
                      <div class='label_image'>Caption:</div>
                      <div class='input_image'><input name='caption2' type='text' maxlength='200' class='inputbox'/></div>
                    </div>

                    <label><input type='submit' name='submitBtn' class='sbtn' value='Upload' /></label>
                  </div>
                  <iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;'></iframe>
                </form>
              </div>


            </div>
          </center>
        </div>

        <div id='controlbuttons'>

          <a href='storyslide_write.php?type=<?php echo $type; if (isset($_GET['ID'])) { echo "&ID=" . $ID; } if (isset($_GET['n'])) { echo '&n=c'; } if (isset($_GET['revised'])) { echo '&revised=' . $_GET['revised']; } if (isset($_GET['c'])) { echo '&c=' . $_GET['c']; } ?>' id='savebutton' style='visibility:hidden;'><img src='adminimages/save.jpg' alt='Done' border='0' /></a>
          <a href='admin.php'><img src='adminimages/home.jpg' border='0' alt='Main Menu'/></a></div>
        </div> <!-- end wrapper -->
      </body>
      </html>
      <?php } ?>
```

The input that I want to remove so we only have 1 image upload input is:

```
<input name='myfile' type='file' size='70' class='inputbox'/>
```

The validation needs to be removed from the first file in order to do this successfully.

I had a few stabs at this myself and noticed that the input field was being referenced in upload.php by the name of the input "myfile", so I searched the upload.php for anhything relating to this input name I found the following and tried to remove:

```
while(file_exists($time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name']))  
{  
    $time++;  
}

$thumb_target_path = $thumb_destination_path . $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];

 $filename = $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
```

To no avail however...

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code, it removes `$_FILES['myfile']` from everywhere, including if statements, SQL queries, etc.:

**Upload.php**

```
// Edit upload location here
$thumb_destination_path = "../storyslide_thumbs/";
$large_destination_path = "../storyslide_large/";

$type = $_POST['type'];
if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
  $ID = (int) $_POST['ID'];
}

$caption = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['caption']);
$caption2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['caption2']);

if ($type == "article" || $type == "editarticle") {
  $sql="select a.title, a.category, c.title as cattitle, s.section as stitle, c.type from article a, category c, section s WHERE c.catID=a.category AND c.sectionid=s.sectionid AND a.articleID='$ID'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);

  $stitle = html_entity_decode($stitle);
  $stitle = punct_remove($stitle);
  $linktitle = html_entity_decode($title);
  $linktitle = punct_remove($linktitle);
  $cattitle = html_entity_decode($cattitle);
  $cattitle = punct_remove($cattitle);

  if ($category=='43') {
    $link = "/fans/obituaries/$ID-$linktitle..html";
  } else {
    if ($type=="Blog") {
      $ID = "b$ID";
      $cattitle = $cattitle . "-" . $category;
    } else {
      $cattitle = $category . "-" . $cattitle;
    }
    $link = "/$stitle/$cattitle/$ID-$linktitle.html";
  }
} elseif ($type == "player") {
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM player WHERE playerID='$ID'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);

  $name = html_entity_decode($name);
  $name = punct_remove($name);

  $link = "/players/squad/$ID-$name.html";
} elseif ($type == "match") {
  $sql="select r.versus, r.venue, s.year FROM regmatch r, season s WHERE r.matchID='$ID' AND r.season=s.seasonID";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);

  if ($venue=='Home') {
    $teams = "Stanlow V $versus";
    $teams2 = "Stanlow_vs_" . str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus));
  }
  else {
    $teams = "$versus V Stanlow";
    $teams2 = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus)) . "_vs_Stanlow";
  }

  $year = str_replace("/", "-", $year);

  $sql="select count(*) as num3 FROM loungeimages WHERE matchID='$ID'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);



  if ($_POST['p']=="ao") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/awayteam.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="bb") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/bookiekiller.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="tn") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/teamnews.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="s") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/scores.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="l") {
    if ($num3>0) {
      $sql="select MIN(imgID) as minumumimage FROM loungeimages WHERE matchID='$ID' GROUP BY matchID";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      extract($row);

      $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/lounge/$minumumimage.html";
    }
    else { 
      $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/lounge.html";
    }
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="fv") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/fansviews.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="fr") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/fansmatchreport.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="ob") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/offtheball.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="mq") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/matchquotes.html";
  } elseif ($_POST['p']=="mr") {
    $link = "/match/$year/$ID-$teams2/" . strtolower($venue) . "/matchreport.html";
  }
}

elseif ($type == "match2") {
  $sql="select r.versus, r.venue FROM regmatch2 r WHERE r.matchID='$ID'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);

  if ($venue=='Home') {
    $teams = "Stanlow V $versus";
    $teams2 = "Stanlow_vs_" . str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus));
  }
  else {
    $teams = "$versus V Stanlow";
    $teams2 = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($versus)) . "_vs_Stanlow";
  }

  if ($_POST['p']=="ao") {
    $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/aboutoppo.html";
  } 
  elseif ($_POST['p']=="bb") {
    $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/de_ja_lards_best_bet.html";
  }
  elseif ($_POST['p']=="tn") {
    $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/teamnews.html";
  }
  elseif ($_POST['p']=="mr") {
    $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/matchreport.html";
  }
  elseif ($_POST['p']=="rank") {
    $link = "/match/perfectseason/$ID-$teams2/andys_old_rankin.html";
  }
}


elseif ($type == "event") {
  $link = "/fans/diary.html";
} elseif ($type == "picsubcat") {
  $sql = "SELECT s.title as stitle, c.catID, c.title as ctitle, MIN(p.imgID) as imgID, se.section FROM picturesubcategory s, category c, picturetable p, section se WHERE c.sectionid=se.sectionid AND s.piccatID='$ID' AND s.catID=c.catID AND p.piccatID=s.piccatID";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("<script language='javascript'>alert('" . $sql . "');</script>");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);

  $ctitle = html_entity_decode($ctitle);
  $ctitle = punct_remove($ctitle);
  $stitle = html_entity_decode($stitle);
  $stitle = punct_remove($stitle);
  $section = strtolower($section);

  $link = "/$section/$catID-$ctitle/$stitle/$imgID.html";
} elseif ($type == "paypal") {
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM paypalitems WHERE itemID='$ID'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad select statement");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  extract($row);
  $name = str_replace(" ", "_", $name);
  $name = urlencode($name);
  $link = "/products/" . $ID . "-" . $name . ".html";
} elseif ($type == "lookalike") {
  $link = "/funnies/lookalikes/1.html";
} elseif ($type == "wallpaper") {
  $link = "/gear/wallpapers/1.html";
}

$result = 0;

$time = time();

while (file_exists($time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name']))
{
  $time++;
}

$large_target_path = $large_destination_path . $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name'];

$filename = '';
$filename2 = $time.'-'.$_FILES['myfile2']['name'];

if ((!isset($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name']) || $_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'] == "")) {
  $result = 3;
} else {
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (getimagesize($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'])) {
      if (((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'], $large_target_path))) {
        $result = 1;

        $image_dim2 = getimagesize($large_target_path);

        if (($image_dim2[0] != 230 || $image_dim2[1] != 199)) {
          $result = 4;
          unlink($large_target_path);
        } else {

          if (isset($_POST['f'])) {
            $publishingdate = $_POST['date'];
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO storyslide_future (thumb, large, thumbcaption, largecaption, link, publishingdate) VALUES ('$filename', '$filename2', '$caption', '$caption2', '$link', '$publishingdate')";
            $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad insert statement");</script>');

          } else {

            $sql = "DELETE FROM storyslide WHERE thumbID='16'";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! bad delete statement");

            $sql1 = "UPDATE storyslide SET thumbID=thumbID+1";
            $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad update statement");</script>');

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO storyslide (thumbID, thumb, large, thumbcaption, largecaption, link) VALUES ('1', '$filename', '$filename2', '$caption', '$caption2', '$link')";
            $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("Error! bad insert statement");</script>');
          }

        }
      }
    } else {

      $result = 2;

    }
  } else {
    $result = 5;
  } 
}

sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>




<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this but the upload progress seems to just hang and nothing happens. Like the upload progress isn't happening.